# How are API keys in Nuget.config used by nuget clients?

Tags: nuget, devops

My company have set up an internal Nuget repository that is normally only available from clients inside our corp network. Most of our dev teams use cloud based devops tools(Azure) however, so the build agents need access to the nuget repo during builds.

To remedy this we are now building a proxy that will require an api key to always be slapped onto the requests (pushing Nuget packs can only be done from inside the network). We are still in the exploration phase and one thing we have noticed is that if we set up an [API key in clients' Nuget.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file?source=recommendations#apikeys) it doesn't seem to be passed along in the requests.

We have been unable to find documentation on how/when the configured API keys are being applied, and Fiddler isn't capturing the traffic at all. But in the receiving (proxy) end we don't see that the API keys are actually being applied by the Nuget client. How/when are the API keys used?

[EDIT]
We have also tried setting up package source credentials in the Nuget.config but we still don't see them being passed as part of requests from a nuget client (Rider or VS2022 in this case). The documentation only explain how to apply credentials, but it doesn't go into how they are actually being employed by nuget clients.

Anyone in the know about how packaged credentials should be passed to the nuget server/API?

Comment: What NuGet calls an "API Key" is only used when pushing packages. For everything else, NuGet uses what it calls "package source credentials".  [The nuget.config file reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file) have some info.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried adding package source credentials (via Powershell's CLI) and I see that they end up as expected in Nuget.config. But when I then refresh for that Nuget source and check what the requests look like there's no Authorization header in the requests. I had extected a "Basic" authentication in this case but the header wasn't even present. 

I see no technical description for how Nuget is actually employing the credentials in the article.

Comment: The creds are sent via the HTTP Authorization header, but only after a first request where no auth is sent, and the server responds with 401. If the server responds with a different error, NuGet's not going to send creds. Also if you didn't set creds with `dotnet nuget [add|update] source` or `nuget.exe source [add|update]`, then you need to be careful to correctly match the source name in the two sections of the nuget.config. Otherwise, nuget will think the creds are for a different source.